# How to catch value of parameter in Apache2 CGI

Tags: bash, web-applications, shell, apache2, cgi

I have a little apache2 CGI application on the Ubuntu. The CGI handler is bash shell script.
My client application is **search.html**:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="/cgi-bin/search.sh" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="searchKey" size="10"></input>
    <input type=SUBMIT value="search">
<form>
</body>
</html>
```

firstly, I just want to catch value of "searchKey" parameter in server side. I tried like following, but displaying nothing.
**search.sh** is:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Content-type:text/plain 
echo ""

echo $SEARCHKEY
```

Guys, can you tell me how to catch value of the parameter in the server side?

**UPDATE**

thank you for all answers.I understood that to get a value of post request need to read data from STDIN. 
i tried as Ithcy suggest like following

```
#!/bin/bash
echo post=$(</dev/stdin)
echo 'content length:'$CONTENT_LENGTH
echo 'content:'$post
```

it was displaying only that:

```
content length:30
content:
```

why is content nothing? do i need to do more configure on Apache server to read post data?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

POSTs will come through STDIN.

```
#!/bin/bash
POST=$(</dev/stdin)
echo $POST
```

But you really should look at using perl (or python, PHP, etc) if you can, as Glenn Jackman suggests.

Answer (score 2):

The whole querystring is represented in the `$QUERY_STRING` variable. You can see this by running `env` without arguments in your shell script.

Example for getting only the searchKey value:

```
echo $QUERY_STRING | sed 's/searchKey\=\([^&]\+\).*/\1/'
```

**Update**: I'm sorry, this only applies if you are using GET to post your form. I didn't read the details =/

If you really need to read POSTs, this page may help you: http://digitalmechanic.wordpress.com/2008/02/21/handling-post-data-in-bash-cgi-scripts/
I didn't get it to work, though.

Comment: POSTs just pass the data via stdin, so can be handled just like any other data passed via stdin... which I have no experience doing in shell scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry no one answered your question all these months.  This works:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo
echo post=$(</dev/stdin)
echo 'content length:'$CONTENT_LENGTH
echo 'content:'$post
```

You must insert a blank line after /bin/bash (if not echo, **printf "\n"** will do)

Comment: using `</dev/stdin` works for me, unlike using `cat` or `read`

Answer (score 1):

This is good documentation about the CGI protocol: http://hoohoo.ncsa.illinois.edu/cgi/

I'd suggest you consider using a language (such as Perl) with a good CGI library so you don't have to reinvent a wheel that's been perfected years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
echo $1
```

instead of

```
echo $SEARCHKEY
```

Comment: klausbyskov, thank you for the answer.
But it's still displaying nothing

Answer (score 0):

Try this script to list content of your input:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'content length:'$CONTENT_LENGTH
read StringInBox
echo $StringInBox
```